# input value same as predefined list but getting a different output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Ive written a program which takes in the name and age of multiple entries seperated by a comma and then sepearates  the aplhabets from the numerics and then compares the name with a pre defined set/list.
If the entry doesnt match with the pre defined data, the program sends a message"incorrect entry" along with the element which didnt match.
heres the code:

```
from string import digits

print("enter name and age")
order=input("Seperate entries using a comma ',':")
order1=order.strip()
order2=order1.replace(" ","")
order_sep=order2.split()
removed_digits=str.maketrans('','',digits)
names=order.translate(removed_digits)
print(names)
names1=names.split(',')
names_list=['abby','chris','john','cena']

names_list=set(names_list)

for name in names1:
    if name not in names_list:
        print(f"{name}:doesnt match with predefined data")
```

the problem im having is even when i enter chris or john, the program treats them as they dont belong to the pre defined list

```
sample input : ravi 19,chris 20
output:ravi ,chris 
ravi :doesnt match with predefined data
chris :doesnt match with predefined data
```

also i have another issue , ive written a part to eliminate whitespace but i dont know why, it doesnt elimintae them

```
sample input:ravi , chris 
ravi :doesnt match with predefined data 
()chris :doesnt match with predefined data
```

theres a space where ive put parenthesis.

any suggestion to tackle this problem and/or improve this code is appreciated!

Comment: look at the output of your own print carefully, your issue is shown there. `ravi ,chris ` Notice the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the parts can be simplified, especially when removing the digits. As long as the input is entered with a space between the name and age, you can use split() twice. First to separate the entries with `split(',')` and next to separate out the ages with `split()`. It makes comparisons easier later if you store the names by themselves with no punctuation or whitespace around them. To print the names out from an iterable, you can use the `str.join()` function. Here is an example:

```
print("enter name and age")
order = input("Seperate entries using a comma ',': ")
names1 = [x.split()[0] for x in order.split(',')]
print(', '.join(names1))

names_list=['abby', 'chris', 'john', 'cena']
for name in names1:
    if name not in names_list:
        print(f"{name}:doesnt match with predefined data")
```

This will give the desired output:

```
enter name and age
Seperate entries using a comma ',': ravi 19, chris 20
ravi, chris
ravi:doesnt match with predefined data
```